# Спецсимвол (легкое затемнение) некорректно отображается на ios

Tags: css, ios

░░░░░░░░░░░░░░

Вот такие спецсимволы вначале не хотели отображаться красиво на мак. Полечил добавлением шрифта Arial
Было:

```
body {font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

Стало:

```
body {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
```

Но проблема осталась на айфонах (и возможно на андроидах)
Рабочий пример [тут](https://yopt.org/postavshiki/10394)
[image: Должно выглядеть так]
[image: А выглядит так]

Буду крайне признателен, если что-то подскажет, как справиться с проблемой. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема и останется.
"Затенение" - это начертание символов, такое же, как буквы. В разных шрифтах оно может быть разным, и даже отсутствовать (как в Гельветике и шрифтах мобильных систем).

Вообще-то, маскировку таким образом применять - дурной тон, но если так уж надо, лучше сделать иначе - в качестве символа использовать какой-нибудь нейтральный, например, `w`, задать элементу с этими символами прозрачный цвет и полутень в качестве фона (полупрозрачный цвет, фоновый рисунок или градиент):

```css
span {
  color: transparent;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-60deg, black 0, black 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 3px);
  user-select:none;
}
```

```html
Телефон: <span>wwwwwww</span> <button>рег.</button>
```

Comment: Крутой способ, спасибо за идею!